# How to show iOS screen on a projector like Steve Jobs did on his keynotes?

Tags: ios, projector

How to show iOS screen on projector like Jobs did? Too many people ask me how to do this... They also want iPhone frame image like exactly Jobs did. (the iPhone frame image is optional)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many iOS devices (some with previous generation hardware and running older iOS).

If the original question is referring to iPad, iPad 2, iPod Touch 4th Generation, and iPhone 4, there are now two new optional Apple accessories available at Apple Store (US).

Both allows video out (up to 1080p and mirroring for iPad 2; up to 720p with no mirroring for the rest i.e. iPad, iPod Touch 4th gen, and iPhone 4):

- [Digital AV Adapter](http://www.apple.com/s/Aj4u9q1)
- [Apple VGA Adapter](http://www.apple.com/s/AS0C1d9)

Answer (score 5):

About the iPhone/iPad frame images - they are available when you're a registered iOS developer: http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/
They are a very high quality Photoshop files (for printing and for screen use).

Answer (score 4):

In the past Steve has used a specially modified iPad and iPhone for screen display, tethered with an on-stge cord. The iPad 2 has been [widely reported](http://www.macworld.com/article/158439/2011/03/ipad2.html) to do screen mirroring via the Apple HDMI adaptor. For your purposes, the iPad 2 would seem to be the best choice.

> Exclusive to the iPad 2 that will be
>   hailed by educators, presenters, and
>   anyone else who has ever wanted to
>   show off their iPad’s screen to a
>   large crowd: video mirroring. When
>   connected to the HDMI adapter, the
>   iPad 2 will display a duplicate
>   version of the contents of its screen
>   on an external monitor. Want to demo
>   an education app via a projector or
>   HDTV for a classroom full of kids? The
>   iPad 2 makes it possible.
>
> In mirroring mode, the iPad’s
>   interface is crystal clear. It looks
>   great. Because the iPad’s video
>   interface is a 4:3 aspect ratio,
>   you’ll find black bars on the sides of
>   the TV when in mirroring mode. The
>   bars grow even wider if you put the
>   iPad in portrait orientation, but the
>   image of an iPad 2 in portrait mode
>   still looks good—albeit smaller—on an
>   HDTV.

Comment: I cant' find it again, but I thought I read that the first iPad is also supported. Only at a lower resolution.

Comment: It isn't. The iPad only supports video out, not mirroring, using the same video out adapter as the iPad 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so hard thankfully.

If you aren't fussed about having the visual of the device hardware, simply:

1. Plug your iPad or iPhone into your Mac.
2. Open Quicktime Player on your Mac (easily found with Spotlight)
3. Click File > New Movie Recording
4. A popup will appear with the inbuilt camera on, disregard this and click the small arrow next to the record button (red icon)
5. Choose your iPhone/iPad
6. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I would say you could use a lighting to HDMI adapter, or stream it to an Apple TV but I'm sure that Steveused, but he probably had a special device that could do that.

Answer (score -2):

Use http://www.airserver.com better than a wired solution based on video interfaces. 
It is about 15$, but its worth.

Comment: You should elaborate on **why** it's better and / or why it's worth it.