# iPad 2 HDMI out connecter

Tags: ipad

Can the iPad 2's HDMI out adapter, work on the iPhone 4 with ios4.3, as a complete mirror, rather than just video out.

Also on the iPad 2 when using the HDMI out mirror will the onscreen keyboard be displayed on the external screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPad 2's HDMI adapter works as mirror for the iPad but only as video out for the iPhone 4. Also it's only in 720p for the iPhone.

the onscreen keyboard being displayed but my best guess is yes unless your using a bluetooth keyboard.

Hope that helps.

> *EDIT* : it does indeed display the keyboard. When using as a mirror it will only fill the aspect ratio of the iPad but when watching a movie it will fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan, yes to both your questions.

A similar and more complete answer is at [How to show iOS screen on a projector like Steve Jobs did on his keynotes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10360/how-to-show-ios-screen-on-projector-like-jobs-does/10371#10371)